# nginx location matching for url params only

Tags: nginx

I need to rewrite any root subdomain requests and append locale params if they aren't already there.  e.g. -> de.example.com needs to be rewritten as ->  de.example.com/?locale=de. then I proxy it off to the app.

2 questions:

1) is this the correct approach? or should I be using regex instead here? (new to this
so if other problems, please lmk)

2) is there a way to log things inside the location block?  Having trouble getting same config working on another server, logging would help.  (e.g logging what args is if it isn't matching, or if it matches on another location block).
It only needs to happen on the root page so this is my current config

```
#existing default (nonsubdomain block)
server {
 server_name _;
 root /var/www/web_app;
 try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
 location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
      }
}

#just added for subdomain 
server {

  server_name de.example.com;
  root /var/www/web_app;

  location / {
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
 }  
  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
  location = / {
   if ($args != locale=de ){ 
    rewrite ^ $scheme://de.example.com/?locale=de permanent;
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you indicate that there're multiple subdomains? like `de.example.com`, `en.example.com`, etc

Comment: only one subdomain inside this server block. there is another server block (edited, now above) w/ which uses server_name _;  but my understanding was that if the hostname request matched, it would use this block as opposed to the less specific (this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) is this the correct approach? or should I be using regex instead here? (new to this so if other problems, please lmk)

You should use `$arg_locale != de` instead of `$args != locale=de`. Look at the docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_

> 2) is there a way to log things inside the location block? Having trouble getting same config working on another server, logging would help. (e.g logging what args is if it isn't matching, or if it matches on another location block). It only needs to happen on the root page so this is my current config

Debug log: http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html